# Apps installed from the Microsoft Store disappear after a reboot

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, microsoft-store, windows-10-apps

*This question was originally posted on Ask Ubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1382302/1165986), but since it turns out to be common to non-Ubuntu WSL distributions (and even non-WSL apps), I was asked to recreate it here on Super User.  The original will be closed, but it's still there for reference for now.  Please direct all comments and answers to this Super User question.*

After installing an app from the Microsoft Store on Windows 10, it initially works.  However, when I restart Windows, the app is gone.  It does not appear in the Start Menu any longer.  What could be causing this?

I originally noticed the problem when installing Ubuntu 20.04 using WSL2 from the Microsoft Store. It worked fine when the system was running, but on restart it was uninstalled or disappeared. I could reinstall it again, and it would work, but each reboot would cause it to disappear again.

From the comments, we determined that:

- WSL itself was still installed.  The `wsl -l -v` command worked, but showed:

  ```
  Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions
  ```

  Before rebooting, however, it correctly showed Ubuntu 20.04 at version 2.
- Also, the Store packages seem to be uninstalled entirely.

  After installing Ubuntu, running `Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\' | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'install.tar.gz' } | ForEach-Object { $_.Directory.BaseName }` in PowerShell results in:

  ```
  ConicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu20.04onWindows_2004_2021.825.0_x64__79rhkplfndgsc
  ```

  But after rebooting, it shows no results.
- The same problem occurs with Ubuntu 18.04.
- And then we found that the same problem occurs even with non-WSL apps installed from the Store.

Comment: WIN-DOS running in a VM with "restore to initial state at reboot" option set?

Comment: @Hannu A good question, but since WSL itself sticks around, that can't be the issue, right?  I'm still suspecting that something is resetting some state on each reboot, though.  But it only *seems* to be impacting Store apps, not the complete system.

Comment: I never did get a response on Ask Ubuntu on two other questions, though.  (1) Is your Windows account an Administrator? (2) Is the Windows account managed by any organization such as a company or school?

Comment: Also, please list any specific non-WSL apps that you've tried installing, just for completeness.  Thanks!

Comment: @Hannu Oh wait, that *could* be an issue if the "initial state" included WSL, but it would still be odd for that option to be set after enabling WSL but before installing Apps, I would think.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, This account has managed by Administrator and second one is this work pc means windows is managed by company

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I was installed pdf x app from store but this also get wiped after reboot.

Comment: There are sneaky ways to "restore at reboot" on normal PC:s also... I would guess something of that kind actually is active in this case. Compare to e.g. how Linux "live" disks allow to store personal data on a second partition on a USB-stick,

Comment: @HanumantGaikwad How close does [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-resets-after-restart/e3747f02-55ac-475d-825b-26a41f66d7c5?auth=1) sound to what you are seeing?  Does the desktop get reset?  Background?  If so, you might try the steps listed in there.  The one that ultimately worked was doing a Windows Upgrade and selecting the 'Repair' option.

Comment: @Hannu Right - I'm just trying to think of ways that might work so we could help the OP determine if that's the case (and how to fix it, if so).  At least two things seem to be reset on reboot in this case (1) `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` (since the packages disappear, (2) the user registry (HKCU), since WSL doesn't show any installed distributions, and it obtains this information from there.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if you ever got this working, but proposing a possible solution for WSL (and only WSL) for others that might run into it.  Of course, it's best if you can solve the core issue so that Apps don't get uninstalled after rebooting, but if you really need WSL without the App, you can get by with this method.

If the installed Microsoft Store apps are being reset, but WSL itself is still installed (which we verified via `wsl -l -v`), then you should be able to "disconnect" the Ubuntu WSL installation from the Store installation.

Note:  This assumes that files in your Windows `Documents` directory are *not* being reset.

To do this:

- Install "Ubuntu" from the Microsoft Store.  You could also use one of the "versioned" releases such as "Ubuntu 20.04", but note that you'll need to adjust the names in the commands below accordingly.
- Launch it for the first time so that it asks you to create a username and password.
- Exit it
- Start PowerShell
- `wsl -l -v` to show the installed distributions.  There should be just the one `Ubuntu`.
- Also from PowerShell:

  ```
  wsl --shutdown
  cd ~\Documents
  mkdir wsl\instances\MyUbuntu
  mkdir wsl\images
  wsl --export Ubuntu wsl\images\ubuntu.tar
  wsl --import MyUbuntu wsl\instances\MyUbuntu wsl\images\ubuntu.tar --version 2
  wsl --set-default MyUbuntu
  wsl -l -v # should show both Ubuntu and MyUbuntu in the list
  wsl
  ```
- You should now be in your `MyUbuntu` instance.  Confirm this with `echo $WSL_DISTRO_NAME`.
- You should also be root, since WSL doesn't automatically set the default user for `--import`ed instances.  To change this:

  ```
  sudo -e /etc/wsl.conf
  ```
- Add the following to that file:

  ```
  [user]
  default=yourWSLusername
  ```

  This should be set to the username you created during the initial Ubuntu installation above.
- Exit WSL (back to PowerShell) and:

  ```
  wsl --terminate MyUbuntu
  ```

That should be it.  You should now have a `MyUbuntu` WSL distribution/instance installed that will survive even if the Ubuntu *app* gets uninstalled after reboot.

To run it, use the `wsl` command instead of the `ubuntu` command.  You can add a shortcut in your Start menu to `wsl` if you'd like.